# How to substitute several regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, file

I would like to loop on every lines from a .txt file and then use `re.sub` method from Python in order to change some contents if there is a specific pattern matcing in this line.

But how can I do that for two different pattern in the same file ?

For example, here's my code :

```
file = open(path, 'r')
output = open(temporary_path, 'w')

for line in file:
    out = re.sub("patternToChange", "patternToWrite", line) #Here I would like to also do the same trick with "patternToChange2 and patternToWrite2 also in the same file
    output .write(out)
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Could you please provide a very basic example of input and expected output? I couldn't quite catch the idea.

Comment: Can you provide a few sample lines from the file and also describe what you wish to find and what you wish to replace? From a pure stance, you're current code **will** literally find `patternToChange` and replace it with `patternToWrite`.

Comment: Can't you just run `re.sub` again, but taking `out` as its input, and using your new patterns?  If you saved the result back to `out`, you wouldn't need to make any other changes.

Comment: Does the python syntax allow for `re.sub(...).sub(...)` in one line? If not, Scott's idea is correct where you would do `out = re.sub(pattern1, write1, line)` then `out = re.sub(pattern2, write2, out)`

Comment: Why don't you read the whole file into a string, do the 2 sub's on it, then write it back. It's the cleanest way. It's very rare a regex doesn't apply to spanned lines...

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be best to apply all of your regex(es) to the string, one at a time, before you write it to the file. Maybe something like this?

```py
for line in file:
    out = re.sub('patternToChange', 'patternToWrite', line)
    out2 = re.sub('patternToChange2', 'patternToWrite2', out)
    output.write(out2)
```

The above code worked fine for me - [try it here](https://repl.it/repls/PrivateJuvenileTransfer) if you'd like. Also, be sure to `.close()` your files when you're done, or the output might not show up in them.